# How to get `prints` method outside the method using logger

Tags: ruby, logging

I am using `gem 'logging'`. And I have bunch of methods where I can not use logger instance, but I would like to get log message from this method using logger outside of the class. For example:

```
class Main
  def method
    p 'First log message'
    execute some steps
    p 'Another log message'
  end
end
```

How can I log those two messages outside of the class using my logger like this: `logger.warn(method)` but as separate logs:

```
... WARN: 'First log message'
... WARN: 'Another log message'
```

**UPDATE:**
Possible solution is to make logger global:

```
module Kernel
  def logger
    @logger ||= Logging.logger(STDOUT)
  end
end
```

**UPDATE 2:**

```
module Logging
  module Loggable

    def self.included(base)
      base.extend(ClassMethods)
    end

    module ClassMethods
      def logger
        Logging.logger(STDOUT)
      end
    end

    def logger
      self.class.logger
    end

  end
end

Object.send :include, Logging::Loggable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As by [documentation](https://github.com/TwP/logging), you might call the respective methods directly on `Logging` class:

```
Logging.logger(STDOUT).warn 'ghgh'
W, [2015-03-07T09:04:30.601189 #19126]  WARN : ghgh
```

or you might declare global variable:

```
$logger = Logging.logger(STDOUT)
$logger.warn 'ghgh'
```

or you might query the logger instance from within your method:

```
lg = Logging.logger['my-logger']
lg.warn 'ghgh'
```

Hope it helps.

**UPD** To make an instance of `Logging` available in any instance of any class, one might use something like:

```
module IncludeLogger
  def logger 
    @logger ||= Logging.logger(STDOUT)
  end
end
Object.send :include, IncludeLogger
```

The above would inject `logger` method into any object.

Comment: I think I would like to make logger global, like here with Yell: https://github.com/rudionrails/yell#adding-a-logger-to-all-classes-at-once-global-logger. But I am not sure how to that with Logging class.

Comment: I am getting `undefined local variable or method `logger' for main:Object (NameError)` exception. I required file with module.

Comment: Oh, sorry, there was a superfluous `self.` modifier before method. Try the corrected code, please.

Comment: That's awesome! Thank you! I got question. Is there any major difference between your solution and the one I attached?

Comment: In general — no, they do pretty the same thing: monkeypatching `Object`. The solution above is a bit more customizable, though. E.g. you might patch only a bundle of selected classes.

Comment: I see. I will use your solution, that looks awesome. Thank you!

Comment: `Object.send :include, IncludeLogger` --- Wut? Is it not a _non sense_ way to use `#send` approach ?

Comment: Well. I don't understand what that means 'bad design'. I am not a pro.

Comment: @KirillZhukov Please don’t pay attention, this guy hates me personally for pointing at his wrong answers. Everything is fine with this approach.

Comment: @KirillZhukov  Get the book `POODR` to know why `#send` and `public_send` in this kind of problem is not considered as a perfect tool.

Comment: @mudasobwa, alright... I implemented `Loggable` like it is done in `Yell` class, check update please. How is it? I'd guess, there is not significant different between provided implementations, but still. Which one would be 'better'?

Comment: @KirillZhukov The upd2-impl adds `logger` to both instances _and_ eigenclasses. Whether you really need to call it like `MyClass.logger`, it makes sense. If you simply want to yield an ability to call `logger.method` from within your class’ methods, it is a bit superfluous. But everything is still fine.

Comment: Cool. I prefer to call implicitly like `logger.debug ...`, all of the solutions provides such ability. Actually I have more methods and functionality for logger, and if I put them inside IncludeLogger/Kernel, those methods will be global for everyone. I could not find any way to make them private. That's not so important though. Either solution is perfect for me.

Comment: @KirillZhukov You are welcome. I did not get the reason of “privating” methods, but [here you go](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Module.html#method-i-private): `Object.send :private, :logger`.